# How can I tell that I have done enough literature research? Is there a specific amount of time one should devote to it?

Tags: research-process, research-topic, literature-review, literature-search, patents

Finding and gathering references can be a quite time-consuming task as it demands one to get accustomed with the terminology and concepts of the related topic / area.

How much time should one devote on searching existing literature when start working on research project, papers, or thesis?

Comment: Reading is a continuous task, I would not calculate it the way the question suggests.

Comment: As it stands, your question is a survey rather than a request for generally valid information. As such it doesn’t work on our platform (what would be the correct or best answer?) and also won’t help you. What do you actually want to know? Please [edit] your question to address this. An example of a valid question would be: “How can I tell that I have done enough literature research?”

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Done! Thanks a lot for the feedback!

Comment: How long it takes to reach an "aHa" moment is unpredictable. And you don't need to reach that point before you "start" research.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/170186/search-techniques-for-finding-references-at-the-start-of-reviewing-the-literatur

Comment: This is not a good question for this site... but... the pseudo-answer is "it will take longer than you imagine..." ... but/and "start work before you've completed that survey". There's not an easy, simple algorithm to "start research". (If there were, it might be automated by now. Exactly the parts that are not automate-able are what are left for people to do...)